# How to get a view table query (code) in SQL Server 2008 Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I have a view in SQL Server 2008 and would like to view it in Management Studio.

Example:

```
--is the underlying query for the view Example_1
select * 
from table_aView
```

View name: `Example_1`

How to get the query of the corresponding view table (query used to create the view)?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

In Management Studio, open the Object Explorer.

- Go to your database
- There's a subnode `Views`
- Find your view
- Choose `Script view as > Create To > New query window`

and you're done!

[image]

If you want to retrieve the SQL statement that defines the view from T-SQL code, use this:

```
SELECT  
    m.definition    
FROM sys.views v
INNER JOIN sys.sql_modules m ON m.object_id = v.object_id
WHERE name = 'Example_1'
```

Comment: thanks marc....sorry my question still didnt hit the bulls eye.Kindly relook at my question now

Comment: @Sudhan: well did you even **TRY** what I showed? This **WILL** show the query used to create the view! That's what you're looking for, no??

Comment: +1 from me, irrespective of whatever OP is actually trying to do, this 100% answers the question.

Comment: @marc_c ya tried it..i get only the dimension of the view.only the headers

Comment: @Sudhan: well, maybe you don't have the necessary permissions to see the view definition, then! Check out my T-SQL command - does that do provide you're looking for??

Comment: @marc_s i have a small lock symbol prefixed to the view name...does that signify my helpess sitation :D...

Comment: The lock symbol means it is [encrypted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027513/what-is-a-stored-procedure-with-a-padlock-icon-in-sql-2005)

Comment: @Sudhan: so either you are lacking the `VIEW DEFINITION` permission with your user that you're working with - or the view has been created with the `WITH ENCRYPTION` clause and therefore you **cannot** find it's definition ....

Comment: any short key for script to print in query result window.

Answer (score 12):

Use `sp_helptext` before the `view_name`. Example:

```
sp_helptext Example_1
```

Hence you will get the query:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.Example_1
AS
SELECT       a, b, c
FROM         dbo.table_name JOIN blah blah blah
WHERE        blah blah blah
```

sp_helptext will give stored procedures.

Answer (score 1):

if i understood you can do the following

Right Click on View Name in SQL Server Management Studio -> Script View As ->CREATE To ->New Query Window

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, if you have restricted access to the database (IE: Can't use "Script Function as > CREATE To"), there is another option to get this query.

Find your View > right click > "Design".

This will give you the query you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

To get the information of a view, you use the system catalog `sys.sql_module` and the `OBJECT_ID()` function:

```sql
SELECT
    definition,
    uses_ansi_nulls,
    uses_quoted_identifier,
    is_schema_bound
FROM
    sys.sql_modules
WHERE
    object_id
    = object_id(
        'view_name'
    );
```

Another way to get the view information is to use the `OBJECT_DEFINITION()` and `OBJECT_ID()` functions as follows:

```sql
SELECT 
    OBJECT_DEFINITION(
        OBJECT_ID(
            'view_name'
        )
    ) view_info;
```

Answer (score 0):

right-click the view in the object-explorer, select "script view as...", then "create to" and then "new query editor window"

Answer (score 0):

SELECT
definition,
uses_ansi_nulls,
uses_quoted_identifier,
is_schema_bound
FROM
sys.sql_modules
WHERE
object_id
= object_id(
'your view name'
);

Comment: either you can use just like we use for store procedure    sp_helptext then view name

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).